# Commutativity in a Unital Banach Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, banach-algebras

Let $ A $ be a unital Banach algebra and $ S $ a non-empty subset of $ A $. The centralizer of $ S $ is defined as
$$
Z(S) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ a \in A ~|~ \text{$ as = sa $ for all $ s \in S $} \}.
$$
I need to show that if the elements of $ S $ commute with each other, then the elements of $ Z(Z(S)) $ commute with each other.

I know that $ Z(Z(S)) $ is a closed sub-algebra of $ A $ and that $ {\sigma_{A}}(a) = {\sigma_{Z(S)}}(a) $ for any $ a \in Z(S) $. Also, $ S \subseteq Z(Z(S)) $. But I do not see how the commutativity part follows.

Can anybody please give me a hint?

Comment: Could you kindly explain what is meant by ‘$ S $ is commuting’? Do you mean ‘$ Z(S) = A $’?

Comment: @HaskellCurry I think S commuting means $s_1 s_2=s_2 s_1$ for all $s_1,s_2\in S$

Comment: Yes, @HaskellCurry it means exactly as i.a.m just said.

Comment: @CB_Student: Thanks for the clarification! I hope you won’t mind if I incorporate this with an edit.

Comment: Not at all ! Thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has *nothing* to do with banach algebras. It holds in every magma, i.e. set equipped with a binary operation. Also, $S \neq \emptyset$ is a useless and unnatural condition, it should be left out.

Observe that $S \subseteq T$ implies $Z(T) \subseteq Z(S)$ $(\star)$. Since $S$ is commutative, we have $S \subseteq Z(S)$. Applying $(\star)$ this we get $Z(Z(S)) \subseteq Z(S)$. Applying $(\star)$ once again, we get $Z(Z(S)) \subseteq Z(Z(Z(S)))$. But this exactly means that $Z(Z(S))$ is commutative.

Edit: Oh, Haskell and I posted the same proof, simultaneously!

Comment: Gosh... We actually did!

Answer (score 5):

> **Fact:** If $ S $ and $ T $ are subsets of $ A $, then $ S \subseteq T $ implies $ Z(T) \subseteq Z(S) $.

If the elements of $ S $ commute with each other, then $ S \subseteq Z(S) $. Applying the fact above, we obtain $ Z(Z(S)) \subseteq Z(S) $, which then implies that $ Z(Z(S)) \subseteq Z(Z(Z(S))) $. Therefore, the elements of $ Z(Z(S)) $ commute with each other.

Comment: Haskell, Thank you very much. you are brilliant :)

Comment: @HaskellCurry Okay, I get it now. Thank you so much !

Comment: @CB_Student: You’re very much welcome!